# how to connect oracle client to virtualbox

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, portforwarding

So i will do my best to write everything down. I have an oracle virtual box installation with windows 10 pro installed. In this instance i have my oracle db setup. This virual box is setup in a debian 10 server. I created a NAT network between them to create port forwarding. I used the standard 1521 port on both the vm and the server. I also opened 1521 port manually from the server just to be sure. The windows 10 firewall settings have been modified and 1521 port is permitted( again opened manually). When i try to ping to my server's ip it succeeds. The same happens when i ping with ip and 1521 port. Every time i try to connect with an outside oracle client installation ( on the same network ) i have the following error :
ORA-12547: TNS:LOST CONTACT . I also have changed the tnsnames file with the appropriate information so that i can connect.

Any leads on what to check next ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not at all clear what you have.  Is the Windows 10 the host that is running VBox, or is the the os of the VM?  Or vice versa?  Which system has your oracle database?  If your only net adapter on the VM is a NAT adapter, then you will not be able to connect to the VM from outside the VM, because it's IP address will be hidden behind that of the host OS.

Comment: google that error message, your issue isn't network related methinks, example https://databaseinternalmechanism.com/2017/08/22/ora-12547-tnslost-contact/

Comment: @edStevens The windows 10 installation is inside the VM . My host is a debian installation. The oracle database is in the windows 10 vm .I found the solution after some plug and play . Turns out i didnt have the outbound rules for the oracle port set up correctly. This made oracle able to receive requests but not able to answer them. Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was the outbound windows firewall rules. Server was able to receive requests but wasnt able to answer them. Thank you all